# regular expression to match <script type="text/javascript"> but not <script type="text/html">

Tags: javascript, regex

current code (not working):

```
/^script\s*type=\"text\/javascript/i.test(tagName)
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: Drop the starting anchor. Anyway, please be specific about what the input will be. In this particular case, `.indexOf('j') > -1` would work just fine...

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Turned out there was another problem - tagName did not contain the string I was looking for. (clue in the name there!) - so it wasn't just the regex that was the problem... Anyway you people helped me to find the solution, so thanks. Not sure which answer to mark as correct though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To account for the 'type' appearing anywhere within the script tag, and multiple versions of quotes, use:

```
/<script.*?type\s*=\s*.text\/javascript./i
```

You could tighten it up by specifying all quote alternatives instead of '.'.

Answer (score 2):

```
/<script\stype\=\"text\/javascript\">/i
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions and HTML — bad things. How regex will work for next examples (don't forget about single and double quotes)?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> 
<script class="myJS" type="text/javascript"> 
<script type="text/javascript" class="myJS" >
```

Instead of regular expressions, I suggest to use a function like this:

```
function attr_in_str(str, tag, attr) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;

    var elems = div.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].type.toLowerCase() == attr.toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use it:

```
var str = 'This is my HTML <script type="text/javascript"></script>';
var result = attr_in_str(str, 'script', 'text/javascript');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are aware of all the assumption when you use regex to process HTML.

You can just remove the `^` in your current code, since it matches the start of the string.

**EDIT**

Number of spaces should be at least 1, so your should change the `*` after `\s` into `+`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of regex, so I'd do this:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = '<script type="text/html"></script>';

var type = temp.childNodes[0].getAttribute('type');

if (type == 'text/javascript') {
  // ...
}
```

If you were using jQuery, it would be *way* easier:

```
if ($('<script type="text/html"></script>').prop('type') == 'text/javascript') {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a browser out there that would actually execute the JavaScript? If so, this method might be a bit of a security risk.

Comment: Definitely better than a regex!

Comment: @minitech: The element isn't being appended to the document itself, so  I doubt the browser can execute it.